# I'm having problems trying to create a powershell gui with a progress bar that updates smoothly

Tags: powershell, xaml, progress-bar, runspace

I know this is a widely discussed question and i have spent the best part of the week googling and trying things but to no avail....  Now please go easy on me!  I'm not the best at this powershell lark but i have been trying to get a simple GUI going that will allow user to interact and creaet output based on some data gathered.   I kind of got it working but the data agthering takes about 15 minutes so i wanted a progress bar for that,  thats where it all went wrong!  I created the prog bar and it would only update when the data function completed.  Afetr some googloing i realised i needed to try to work out runspaces :(   several days later and i have a script running runspaces but i still cannot get it to update the progress bar :(.  I am sure one of you smart peole will immediately pull my code appart and show me up for how badly its done... as some of you may recognise this end result is based on https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars.html.   thats after many iterations trying other peoples solutions to no avail.  I have tried to massively simplify my code to just work on the direct issue at hand - and thats what i will be ading below.
So i would be extremely grateful if any of you kind folk can point out clearly to me what an idiot i am and where i am going so wrong i would be extremely grateful :)  Just remeber you may need to speeak slowly and and caps as i am obviously hard of learning...  well i feel like this week after banging my head on the wall over damn runspaces! :)
Thanks in advance for any help :)
Oh and i apologise in advance to those who will respond with - "just search - look here is your answser in another link"  I tried and I'm still banging my head on the wall! :)

so here goes - my shonky code - please be kind! :) *(some evidence still hanging around in there of where i have messed about with variable types and some pop ups to confirm progress etc)*

$

```
`global:NumOfDays = 0
$global:selectcb1 = "Y"
$global:selectcb2 = "Y"
$global:selectcb3 = "Y"
$global:outputArr = @()


#create synchash
$global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$global:syncHash) 

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework
         
#create main process
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
    [xml]$xaml = @"
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window" Title="Data Tool" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
        Width = "900" Height = "600" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
        <Grid Margin="3,0,137,1">
            <CheckBox Name="CB1" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CB 1" Margin="40,110,0,0"/>
            <CheckBox Name="CB2" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CB 2" Margin="40,150,0,0"/>
            <CheckBox Name="CB3" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="CB 3" Margin="40,190,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Explain stuff" Margin="47,30,0,0" Width="271" Height="67" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

            <Button Name="Create" Content="Create Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139" Margin="350,400,0,0" Height="22"/>
            <Button Name="Quit" Content="Quit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="600,500,0,0" Height="22"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="explain slider" Margin="200,320,0,0" Width="500" Height="67" />

            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,150,0,0">
                <TextBox Name="slValue" Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Right" Width="40" />
                <Slider Name="slider" Minimum = "5" Maximum="365" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
            </DockPanel>

            <ProgressBar Name="ProgBar" Maximum="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="408" Margin="372,41,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ProgBar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="572,41,0,0" />
            <TextBlock Name="dataprogress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Progress - " Margin="498,15,0,0"/>

            </Grid>
        </Window>
"@
  
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    $syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
    
    [xml]$XAML = $xaml
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
        #Find all of the form types and add them as members to the synchash
        $global:syncHash.Add($_.Name,$global:syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )
    }


    # Create second process handler
    $global:JobCleanup = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
    $global:Jobs = [system.collections.arraylist]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))

    #region Background runspace to clean up jobs
    $jobCleanup.Flag = $True
    $newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
    $newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"          
    $newRunspace.Open()        
    $newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("jobCleanup",$jobCleanup)     
    $newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("jobs",$jobs) 
    $jobCleanup.PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        #Routine to handle completed runspaces
        Do {    
            Foreach($runspace in $jobs) {            
                If ($runspace.Runspace.isCompleted) {
                    [void]$runspace.powershell.EndInvoke($runspace.Runspace)
                    $runspace.powershell.dispose()
                    $runspace.Runspace = $null
                    $runspace.powershell = $null               
                } 
            }
            #Clean out unused runspace jobs
            $temphash = $jobs.clone()
            $temphash | Where {
                $_.runspace -eq $Null
            } | ForEach {
                $jobs.remove($_)
            }        
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1     
        } while ($jobCleanup.Flag)
    })
    $jobCleanup.PowerShell.Runspace = $newRunspace
    $jobCleanup.Thread = $jobCleanup.PowerShell.BeginInvoke()  
    #endregion Background runspace to clean up jobs


    # controls ###################################

    $syncHash.Quit.add_click({
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Quit')
        $global:syncHash.Window.Close()
        $global:syncHash.Clear()
        $global:syncHash.Quit
        $newRunspace.Clear()
        $newRunspace.Dispose()
        #Exit
    })

    
    $global:syncHash.CB1.Add_Checked({
        $global:selectcb1 = "Y" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb1)
    })
    $global:syncHash.CB1.Add_Unchecked({
        $global:selectcb1 = "N" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb1)
    })
    $global:syncHash.CB2.Add_Checked({
        $global:selectcb2 = "Y" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb2)
    })
    $global:syncHash.CB2.Add_Unchecked({
        $global:selectcb2 = "N" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb2)
    })
    $global:syncHash.CB3.Add_Checked({
        $global:selectcb3 = "Y" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb3)
    })
    $global:syncHash.CB3.Add_Unchecked({
        $global:selectcb3 = "N" 
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($selectcb3)
    })

    $global:syncHash.slValue.add_TextChanged({
        $global:NumOfDays = $global:syncHash.slValue.Text
        #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($NumOfDays)  
    })

    $global:syncHash.create.add_click({
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('create')
    })

    $global:syncHash.Window.Add_ContentRendered({
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('gather')

        $newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
        $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
        $newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"          
        $newRunspace.Open()
        $newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash",$SyncHash) 
        $PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        ###############################################
            Function Update-Window {
                Param (
                    $Control,
                    $Property,
                    $Value,
                    [switch]$AppendContent
                )

                # This is kind of a hack, there may be a better way to do this
                If ($Property -eq "Close") {
                    $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke([action]{$syncHash.Window.Close()},"Normal")
                    Return
                }

                # This updates the control based on the parameters passed to the function
                $syncHash.$Control.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{
                # This bit is only really meaningful for the TextBox control, which might be useful for logging progress steps
                    If ($PSBoundParameters['AppendContent']) {
                            $syncHash.$Control.AppendText($Value)
                    } Else {
                       $syncHash.$Control.$Property = $Value
                    }
                }, "Normal")
            } 
        ###############################################
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('gathering')
            for ($i = 1 ; $i -le 100 ; $i++) {
                Start-Sleep -milliseconds 100
                #$global:SyncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([Action]{$global:SyncHash.ProgBar.Value = $i})
                update-window -Control ProgrBar -Property Value -Value $i                
            }
        })
        ###############################################
        $PowerShell.Runspace = $newRunspace
        [void]$Jobs.Add((
            [pscustomobject]@{
                PowerShell = $PowerShell
                Runspace = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
            }
        ))
    })

    #region Window Close 
    $syncHash.Window.Add_Closed({
        Write-Verbose 'Halt runspace cleanup job processing'
        $jobCleanup.Flag = $False

        #Stop all runspaces
        $jobCleanup.PowerShell.Dispose()      
        $PowerShell.Invoke()
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('done')
    })


    ##############################################

$global:syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$global:syncHash.Error = $Error
`
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and a wall of text. You stand a much better chance of getting help if you whittle down your code to a [mcve] or as close as you can get to one, and reduce your narrative to a focused problem description. See also: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).